# How to visualize a list of sequence?

Tags: visualization, charts

This is my data, its order has somewhat meaning

```
data = Uncompress["1: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"];
```

It has many classes

```
Counts@data
(*<|"iang" -> 580, "iao" -> 315, "ia" -> 64, "ian" -> 15, "ang" -> 19, "van" -> 3, "uan" -> 1, "e" -> 1, "an" -> 2|>*)
```

But the same class tend to tie together.

[image]

I want to visualize this data to see what distribution of data. I use this code but it's too tiny to be seen, is a better way to visualize it?

```
col = Association[
       Thread[Union[data] -> Rescale@Range[Length@Union[data]]]];
Graphics[Raster[{data}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", col[#]] &)]]
```

[image]

Comment: `WordCloud[data]`?

Comment: @kglr  If so, it lose order information if using WordCloud or PieChart or something

Comment: Just wondering:  Why did you include a link to the raw data given you posted the `Counts` data?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I post my solution in the following and using the original data so that the sequence of data is maintained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BarChart[Values@Counts[data], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
 BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 PlotRange -> {All, {.5, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Use `Log @ Values @ Counts[data]` as the first argument to get

[image]

**Update:** An alternative is to use `ArrayComponents` to code `data` and use `MatrixPlot`:

```
MatrixPlot[{ArrayComponents[data]}, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
ImageSize -> Length[data]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow It's really a neat example of BarChart

Comment: `Tooltip[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ Normal[Counts[data]]` may display more information such as label.

Comment: @partida, thank you for the accept. `Tooltip` is a great idea.

Comment: I see there is a large white in the background, could you tell me how to delete it such as `ImageCrop` do? Thanks

Comment: @partida, in the updated version i used `PlotRange` to get rid of the white background.

Comment: thank you for your amazing example to visualize it and introduce this neat example for `BarChart`

Answer (score 2):

`Counts@data` lose the order information.
But it may make the question more complicated.

Now the sequence of data is maintained, looks not beautiful.

```
BarChart[Tooltip[
Function[{val}, Style[val, ColorData["Rainbow", col[First@#]]]]
               @Length@#, First@#] & /@ Split[data],
   BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, BarOrigin -> Left, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 500, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   PlotRange -> {All, {.5, 1.5}}]
```

[image]